# lib-usb and libfreenect2 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, homebrew, package, libusb, libfreenect2

I work on MacOS X Yosemite (10.10.5). I'm trying to install libfreenect2 on Mac OS X

When I do "cmake .." from the build directory of [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2). I followed all the [instructions](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/blob/master/README.md#mac-osx) given in the installation page. When I do the command "cmake .." from the build directory, I get this error message:

```
-- Checking for module 'libusb-1.0'
--   No package 'libusb-1.0' found
CMake Error at /Users/Yvanou/anaconda/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:416 (message):
  A required package was not found
```

Yet, I correctly installed libusb 1.6.4 using Homebrew.

Here is the complete log:

```
Yvanou-MacBookPro2015:build Yvanou$ cmake ..
-- using tinythread as threading library
-- Checking for module 'libusb-1.0'
--   No package 'libusb-1.0' found
CMake Error at /Users/Yvanou/anaconda/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:416 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/Yvanou/anaconda/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:589 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  cmake_modules/FindLibUSB.cmake:21 (PKG_CHECK_MODULES)
  CMakeLists.txt:93 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/Yvanou/Documents/libfreenect2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

In addition, I use also **conda** as package manager

Some idea in order to help me ?

Thanks a lot for your time and your precious help!

Comment: It seems to be looking for `libusb v1.0` and you seem to think that v1.6 is suitable... that seems like a mismatch to me.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. How can I downgrade libusb or either change the libusb version cmake seeks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found where my mistake was. I use Anaconda environnement so all packages must be installed under the Anaconda folder. I installed libusb 1.0.21 in the /bin folder of Anaconda and no error message anymore!!